# Migrating Custom Components from Vue2 to Vue3 in Laravel Nova: Issues with $watch Property Replacement

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, laravel-nova

I'm currently upgrading a Laravel Nova project from Nova 3 (which uses Vue2) to Nova 4 (which uses Vue3). And for that reason, we had to do some modification in our custom components.

Like, in Vue3 we have used different method other than `$parent` and `$children` to fetch the child components of parent compoent. This change worked perfectly.

But, in Vue2 there is `$watch` property that used to watch any changes in the child component. And to replicate same functionality in Vue3, I tried several methods, but I am not able to find a solution for it. You can see the difference in below components.

Below are the snippets from both Vue2 and Vue3 components.

**Vue2 Component (Nova 3):**

```
<template>
  <div  class="-mx-8 px-8">
    <div v-for="condition in field.conditions" :key="condition.value">
      <div v-if="condition.value == value">
        <component
          v-bind="$props"
          :key="subfield"
          :field="subfield"
          :is="'form-' + subfield.component"
          v-for="subfield in condition.fields"
        />
        <div class="help-text error-text mt-2 text-danger" v-if="hasError">
          {{ firstError }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { FormField } from 'laravel-nova'
import { Errors } from 'form-backend-validation'

export default {
  mixins: [FormField],

  props: {
    errors: {
      default: () => new Errors(),
    },
    resource: {
      required: true
    },
    resourceId: {
      required: true
    },
    'base-classes': {
      type: Object
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      value: null,
      errorClass: 'border-danger',
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.children.forEach(component => {
      if(component.field !== undefined && component.field.attribute === this.field.observed_field_name) {
        component.$watch(this.field.customProperty || 'value', (value) => {
          this.value = value
        }, {deep: true, immediate: true});
      }
    });
  },

  computed: {
    parent() {
      let parent = this.$parent

      for (let i = 1; i < (this.field.depth || 1); i++) {
        parent = parent.$parent
      }

      return parent
    },

    children() {
      let children = this.parent.$children

      for (let i = 1; i < (this.field.depth || 1); i++) {
        children = children.filter(c => c.$children.length).map(c => c.$children[0])
      }

      return children
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

**Vue3 Component (Nova 4):**

```
<template>
  <div  class="-mx-8 px-8">
    <div v-for="condition in field.conditions" :key="condition.value">
      <div v-if="condition.value == value">
        <component
          v-bind="$props"
          :key="subfield"
          :field="subfield"
          :is="'form-' + subfield.component"
          v-for="subfield in condition.fields"
        />
        <div class="help-text error-text mt-2 text-danger" v-if="hasError">
          {{ firstError }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, watch, onMounted, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';
import { Errors } from 'form-backend-validation';

export default {
  props: {
    errors: {
      default: () => new Errors(),
    },
    resource: {
      required: true
    },
    resourceId: {
      required: true
    },
    'base-classes': {
      type: Object
    },
    field: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },

  setup(props) {
    const value = ref(null);
    const errorClass = 'border-danger';
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();

    // This needs to be carefully handled, as it relies on internal structure
    const children = () => {
      return instance.parent.subTree.children;
    };

    onMounted(() => {
      children().forEach(component => {
        let child = component.children[0];
        if (child.props.field && child.props.field.attribute === props.field.observed_field_name) {
          watch(() => child.component, (newValue) => {
            value.value = newValue;
          }, { deep: true, immediate: true });
        }
      });
    });

    // Computed and methods can be added here as needed

    return { value, errorClass };
  }
}
</script>
```

To explain more the use of `$watch` in project, below is the screenshot for reference.

[image]

[image]

So here in the screenshot you can see there are fields. And each field is a Vue component itself. They can be Nova default fields or they can be custom one.

The vue compoent code pasted at the top, is **Role** field (see in second screenshot) and it is a custom component.
The Role field is dependent on the **Company** field. If **Company** field is blank then **Role** field will get hide and it will get displayed when **Company** field is selected (that too for specific values).

So basically `$watch` property is used to keep watch on changes in **Company** field (specific element within Company component - this.field.customProperty). In Vue2 it was easier to handle this as you can see in the Vue2 code. But, in Vue3 I am not finding proper solution or may be I do not know proper code to watch the compoent.

Does any one know how should I watch child component in Vue3?

> Please note:
>
> I can not directly access parent or child component to
> use **ref** method. Since Laravel Nova does not allow this.
>
> There is new method **dependOn** in Laravel Nova 4 and by using it I
> could avoid using this custom component, but I do not have to use it
> since this custom component is also used for other complex
> resources(pages) in the project.